# Tinymce plugins load from cdn instead of local directory

Tags: angularjs, plugins, get, tinymce, cdn

I have TinceMCE installed for Angular. So when using tiny, I have to do something like the following:

Controller:

```
vm.tinymceOptions = {
        plugins:'layer image hr imagetools',
        toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | code',
        height:'480'
    };
```

And in my view:

```
<form class = "MCEeditor" method="post">
         <textarea ui-tinymce="vm.tinymceOptions" ng-model="vm.tinymceModel"></textarea>
</form>
```

My problem is that when I try to use an  external plugin, a GET request is made to an external CDN instead of my local plugin files. This is the GET request:

```
Request URL:http://cdn.tinymce.com/4/plugins/ss/plugin.min.js
Request Method:GET
```

So essentially, I need a way to point that request to my internal TinyMCE plugin directory instead of this CDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, TinyMCE looks in its own `plugins` folder for the plugin files so if you are loading TinyMCE from a CDN it will look there.

What you can do is use the `external_plugins` option in the configuration and point TinyMCE to the exact location of your plugin file:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#external_plugins

For example:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  ...
  external_plugins: {
    'testing': 'http://www.testing.com/plugin.min.js',
    'maths': 'http://www.maths.com/plugin.min.js'
  }
});
```

Since you are using the TinyMCE / Angular plugin this `external_plugins` code goes in your `vm.tinymceOptions` object.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. It seems like there are some limitations in the ui-tinymce library. For now I will look into why it is hard coded to look into the cdn for the plugins. Is your way mentioned above supposed to work for internal directories as well?

Comment: I use the same directive myself in an Angular project and I use the `external_plugins` property so I can confirm it works. What is your exact code for `tinymceOptions`? Your code in your post does not mention the `ss` plugin at all much let alone `external_plugins`. When you load TinyMCE are there any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems like TinyMCE was not installed properly on our project. Your solution works!